# Do Javascript functions need to be stored in their own file to be called?

Tags: javascript

The situation was as follows:

I had this form in a .php file:

```
<form action="/flash_card/scripts/create_user_gate.php"
            onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" id="uname"
                        onkeydown="return checkInput(event)"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="password">
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><button onclick="return validateForm()" type="button"
                            title="Create user!" name="submit">Create!</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

With this just outside the body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/flash_card/js/webscripts.js"></script>
```

This file contained:

```
/**
 * 
 */

function validateForm(){
    document.write("BURNED INTO YOUR MINDDDD");
    return false;
}

function onlyAlphaNumericAndModifiers(e) {
    var keynum;
    var keychar;
    var numcheck;

    if (window.event) // IE
    {
        keynum = e.keyCode;
    } else if (e.which) // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
    {
        keynum = e.which;
    }
    // letters, numbers, backspace, delete, arrow keys
    if (keynum >= 65 && keynum <= 90 || keynum >= 48 && keynum <= 57
            || keynum == 8 || keynum >= 37 && keynum <= 40 || keynum == 46) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

After fiddling around, I find that I cannot get my validateForm() to fire at all, so I separate it into its own file and suddenly on the click fires validateForm() properly and the text box's onkeydown is firing checkInput correctly as well.

Where did I go wrong? I am assuming that a .js file can contain more than one function, so I must be missing something fundamental.

Comment: No, they don't have to be in their own files. Maybe you have an error somewhere else in the file.

Comment: I now believe the issue might have been a simple caching one... The reason it worked when I split the files was it forced execution with new files. However simply adding functions to an old file would result in the behavior I witnessed because the old file would continually be used. The question now becomes how do I remove caching of .js or any other resource. I have all my .php and .html files set so there is no caching, however apparently this doesn't bubble down to .js...? Very much irritated and confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you may have an error in /flash_card/js/webscripts.js, can you post the source of this file?